# if input is NSArray crashes

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a crash report seemingly when checking whether a value is an `NSArray`.

Here is my code:

```
private static func filter(input: Any?) -> Any? {
  guard let input = input else {
    return nil
  }
  if input is NSArray { // <- Crashes here
    return nil
  } else {
    // Do other stuff
  }
}
```

The crash:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xf3a4 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31c14 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x31bac abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 30
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x33b74 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 116
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x33b00 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 30
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x8730 lookUpImpOrForward + 860
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2cc4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
7  libswiftCore.dylib             0x4058d8 swift_dynamicCastObjCClassImpl(void const*, swift::TargetClassMetadata<swift::InProcess, swift::TargetAnyClassMetadataObjCInterop<swift::InProcess> > const*) + 44
8  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3b4484 tryCastFromObjCBridgeableToClass(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool) + 96
9  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3b3f38 tryCast(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool) + 2448
10 libswiftCore.dylib             0x3b3ca4 tryCast(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*&, bool, bool) + 1788
11 libswiftCore.dylib             0x3b3434 swift_dynamicCast + 208
12 MyApp                           0xe78f8c static MyLogic.filter(input:) + 92 (MyLogic.swift:92)
13 MyApp                           0xe79a8c specialized static MyLogic.processParameters() + 45 (MyLogic.swift:45)
14 libswift_Concurrency.dylib     0x41948 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) + 416
15 libswift_Concurrency.dylib     0x42868 swift_job_runImpl(swift::Job*, swift::ExecutorRef) + 72
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x15944 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x16158 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xda0 _pthread_wqthread + 228
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb7c start_wqthread + 8
```

How can checking whether something is an `NSArray` crash the app? I don't understand.

Comment: What is `input` at the time of the crash? What is the error message from the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know, it's a crash report I'm receiving and this is all the info I've got. I do know it's not going to be an NSArray though.

Comment: The code works fine passing in a few random objects but clearly there's something it doesn't like. Maybe try using `if let _ = input as? NSArray {` instead of `if input is NSArray {`. Without any more details, not sure if that will work in this case or not.

Comment: Why are you working with non Swift types like Any and NSArray? This is very bizarre code.

Comment: @HangarRash In what circumstances would the code you've given avoid crashing compared to using the `is` keyword?

Comment: @Tometoyou I don't know. My suggestion was just a consideration for something to try. I don't know the internals of how `is` works versus using `as?`.

Comment: you could try adding `print("--> type: \(type(of: input))")` just before the `if`, to determine what `input` is made of.

Comment: If there is no way to figure out the data type triggering the crash, there is also no way for you to repeat the crash, and no way to verify if any "solution" is working...

Comment: I think this bit of code needs to be *in* Objective C.

Comment: It is normal that's on a background thread? Could have the object been released in an other thread?

Comment: @Larme Good point, although I've just scoured my code and I can't see how that could happen. Hmm.